# Как парсить данные из WebView

Tags: javascript, android, html, парсер, webview

Делаю мобильное приложение для сайта.
 Сайт не мой, API нет, поэтому его приходится парсить. 
Думал обойдусь только JSOUP, но встал вопрос о том, как обрабатывать javascript кнопки.
 Позадавав вопросы на англоязычном стаке мне сообщили, что с помощью JSOUP мне не обработать javascript. 
Решил делать через WebView, но теперь столкнулся с проблемой -  как спарсить страничку которая сейчас отображена в webview?

Comment: В вашем webview та же самая страничка, которую Вы хотите распарсить? Если да- то разница никакой нет.

Comment: @metalurgus Я читал это, но не могу сообразить как выдрать из этого html кода id элементов

Comment: @АндроидАндроид Я хочу выдрать из этого html кода нужную мне информацию, а WebView вообще сделать невидимым

Comment: @Alex вам не надо делать такие манипуляции. JSOUP сам подрубается к указанной страничке, а потом уже можете парсить ее.

Comment: Через `JSOUP`, например. `JSOUP` может принять в себя строку, которую вы выдерете из WebView

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, ему такие манипуляции необходимы, т. к. у него HTML-код меняется при помощи JavaScript. JSOUP не может выполнить JS

Comment: @metalurgus О, спасибо. Попробую так

Comment: @metalurgus Спасибо, получилось! Только вот грузится теперь раза в 3 дольше

Comment: @Alex, если у вас получилось - опишите решение в ответе - это поможет людям которые в будущем придут с этим же вопросом сюда из гугла. Вы станете их героям, т.к. дадите им готовое решение.

Answer (score 5):

РЕШЕНИЕ:
 Пишем обработчик WebView и втыкаем туда Handler.
Этот Handler будет драть для нас html странички сразу по завершении загрузки.
У меня получилось примерно так:

```
String shit;

@JavascriptInterface
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
    webview.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(false);
    webview.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HtmlHandler");
    webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {      

            webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.HtmlHandler.handleHtml" +
                    "('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");


        }
    });
    webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
    webview.loadUrl("Ваш Сайт");

}
```

Далее пишем класс `MyJavaScriptInterface` в котором мы распарсим выдернутую html страницу с помощью JSOUP:

```
 private class MyJavaScriptInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void handleHtml(String html) {

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        shit = doc.select("span[id=j_id178]").first().text();
        MainActivity.this.setTitle(shit);          

    }
}
```

Естественно еще нужно подключить библиотеку JSOUP в файле build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'   //вот наша библиотека
}
```

Все супер! Теперь заголовок моей Activity принял значение текста в этом id.

Comment: Не совсем понятно что за `shit` ? Откуда её взяли.