# Jsoup Elements, авторизация на сайте(в сети)

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Доброго времени суток.
Интересуют следующие вопросы:
1) Как работать с Elements, а именно: как доставать оттуда ссылки в отдельный string.
2)В универе развернута опытная wi-fi сеть с авторизацией для того, что бы научить горе студентов(меня в.т.ч.) делать быстрые, оптимизированные веб-приложения и т.д. т.п. При подключении к этой сети можно либо подождать на черной странице 20 секунд, либо перейти по определенной ссылке, которая подгружается в html с помощью js на основную страницу авторизации, при переходе по этой ссылке дается доступ в интернет, задание в том, чтобы прошло максимально мало времени от момента подключения к сети до момента получения доступа в интернет. Это предыстория. То есть передо мной стоит задача распарсить основную страницу авторизации, получить эту ссылку и перейти по ней. (как же все просто на словах, аж диву даешься). Что я знаю из того, как и что мне надо делать, мне надо подключиться к странице, дождаться ее полной загрузки, затем в AsyncTask распарсить ее, найти нужную мне ссылку (их несколько, но в нужной присутствует некие несколько кодовых символов  в определенном порядке), затем передать эту ссылку отдельным string(про это 1 вопрос) обратно из AsyncTask, загрузить эту страницу. Понятное дело прикрутив куки, setuseragent(если что-то еще забыл, подскажите, пожалуйста). Грубо говоря, предыстория ни к чему, надо просто зайти на сайт, на нем найти ссылку, по ней перейти. Что я упустил? Правильно ли я это понимаю "на пальцах/словах"? Есть ли у кого-нибудь примеры выковыривания из Elements в String? Есть ли у кого-нибудь примеры чего-то подобного описанному? Одинаковый ли будет эффект для сервера, если я перейду по ссылке, кликнув на нее или перейду на сайт описанным способом через парсер, не будет ли сервер ругаться, заного переправлять меня на страницу авторизации, etc?
Так же буду очень благодарен если кто-нибудь напишет мне в телеграм @mhlchm (https://t.me/mhlchm) и сможет ответить на парочку-тройку вопросов (обещаю не грузить сильно и не доставать), там просто намного удобнее. Спасибо.

Comment: На странице авторизации надо авторизоваться ?) логин пароль вводить надо? Если да, то бывает такое, что эта страница требует еще и токен. Если нет, то всё просто, делаем запрос, получаем страницу, парсим(получаем ссылку) , делаем еще запрос, НО вы написали далее Html подгружается с помощью js , но Jsoup не работает с js, нажав на эту ссылку вы получите изначальный html без отработки скриптов (я почти в этом уверен) .

Comment: Если же для подключения к интернету нужна отработка скриптов, то я вижу другой алгоритм. Так же с помощью jsoup получаем ссылку, но переходим по ней не в jsoup, а в webView и то , для того чтобы WebVIew грузил Js нужны манипуляции

Comment: вот насчет скриптов https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/616616/webview-android-js

Comment: Я еще один момент не учел.. Эта ссылка , которая на странице авторизации всё время разная? Просто получается так что страницу авторизации мы получаем одним браузером (Jsoup) , а переходим по ним другим браузером webView.  В общем есть тут свои тонкости. У меня опыт не большой, поэтому точно не скажу

Comment: @Turalllb нет, токен не просит. Тоесть мы через webView загружаем страницу, а потом ее передаем в jsoup? А нельзя получать страницу и открывать ее одним и тем же браузером? Ну, или, как-нибудь это так представить?

Comment: Вы не поняли последовательность. Jsoup это тоже браузер, только консольный так скажем, у него нет визуализации и еще он не выполняет js. Если выполнение js не обязательно (и без скриптов доступ к интернету появляется) , то можно всё делать в jsoup. Если выполнение скрипов обязательно, то придется немного помучаться. Предлагаю Вам сперва реализовать всё в jsoup и увидеть нужно ли выполнение скрипта , чтобы получить доступ к инету или нет. Дальше действовать по ситуации

Comment: js для этого нужен точно

Comment: я обновил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Как работать с Jsoup в ютубе можно легко найти. Например вот хорошее видео [парсинг Html](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-l8Ji17d65Y&t=5s)  
 
Например запрос на авторизацию

```
Connection.Response resp = Jsoup.connect("http://soft.ru").referrer("http://soft.ru").userAgent(userAgent)
                .data("login", "operator", "password", "1234567")
                .method(Connection.Method.POST).timeout(10000).execute();
```

Парсим полученный ответ `Document doc = resp.parse();`

находим элементЫ  `Elements elements = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "ticketDetailRow");` 
Теперь различные методы для сохранения результата в строку:

```
 String  phoneNumber = elements.get(1).getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "ticketDetailGrid3").get(1).getElementsByIndexEquals(1).attr("value");
```

Тут конечный метод `attr(String str)` сразу возвращает строку. Но чаще приходится переводить результат строку методом `text()`

```
Elements comments = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("name", "col12");
String  comment = comments.get(comments.size() - 1).text();
```

В хроме браузере нажав F12 на вкладке `elements` можно видеть код страницы. Еще проще навести курсор на, в Вашем случае, ссылку и нажав правой кнопкой мыши в меню выбрать *Посмотреть код*

Jsoup это браузер без визуализации, так что сервер не поймет ничего (наверно, если нет изощренных методов защиты).

Приведенный тут мною код для Jsoup для Java, точно такие ли методы для Jsoup на андроид я не знаю.

По поводу выполнения js: как я понял, после выполнения js интернет получен и дальше парсить ничего не нужно. Значит мы получаем переходим по страничке в Jsoup, находим ссылку и переходим по ссылке,но уже не в jsoup, а в webview, он перейдет и исполнит js.  Но может случиться такое: в jsoup переходите по ссылке, парсите, переходите по второй ссылке в webview и тут он ругается, потому что это ссылка полученная другим браузером и ему нужны либо куки либо тот же userAgent, а то и вообще какие нибудь данные, которые выдала первая страница.   Я бы на вашем месте сперва проверил что требует вторая страница сниффером или в том же самом хроме, там есть вкладка network.  Вот вопрос в котором есть похожее решение, только там чуть сложнее. [Как парсить данные из WebView](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476894)